# How to check if Sqflite DB contains a specific id or not? -FLUTTER

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to check the DB if IDs Column contains a specific ID or not? 
I wrote something like this but this is WRONG as h:
 dbHelper.ColID is a String 
posts is a list ; the post model has an int ID ;

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<pageCount ; i++) {
   for(int j=0 ; j<i; j++) {
     if (dbHelper.ColID != posts[i].id){
         dbHelper.insertPost(posts[0]) ;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I used SQL query to get IDs from DB then put 2 loops together:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cachedPostsIDs.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < postsIDs.length; j++) {
        if (cachedPostsIDs.contains(postsIDs[j])) {
          debugPrint("FOUND ${postsIDs[j]} post in the database");
 } else {
          foundPost = false;
          debugPrint("COULDNT FIND ${postsIDs[j]} in cachedPostsIDs");
          break;
        }
      }
```